# If $f(0)+g(0)=0$ and $2f(0)+5g(0)=0$, is $2f(x)+5g(x)$ bounded by $f(x)+g(x)$ on $[0,1]$ if $\lvert f(x)+g(x) \lvert > 0$ for $0 <x \leq 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Suppose that $f(x), g(x) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are smooth functions such that
\begin{equation}
f(0)+g(0)=2f(0)+5g(0)=0
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\lvert f(x)+g(x) \lvert > 0
\end{equation}
for $x \in (0,1]$.

Then, is it possible to find a constant $C>0$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lvert 2f(x)+5g(x) \rvert \leq C \lvert f(x)+g(x) \lvert
\end{equation}
for "all" $x \in [0,1]$?

I find it intuitively plausible but cannot really prove or disprove anything..Could anyone please help me?

Comment: @JoshuaWang My mistake, for overlooking that.  I have therefore deleted my comment.

Comment: Is $2f(0) + 5f(0)$ meant to be $2f(0) + 5g(0)$?

Comment: Oops typo, just corrected it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $f(x) = x + 5x^2$ and $g(x) = -x - 2x^2$.

Then the inequality for $C$ is $$3x \leq 3C x^2$$
which in particular means $\frac1x \leq C$ for every $0 < x \leq 1$, which isn't possible.

Comment: I see... thank you for your counterexample... perhaps is it possible if I replace the constant $C$ by a function related to $f$ and $g$ instead? Your example suggests inverse of derivatives might work.

Comment: @Keith I certainly cannot say that no similar inequality exists without knowing what $C$ depends on.  Note you would need to specialize $C$ in order to be meaningful, however, as  "function related to $f$ and $g$ instead" could yield trivial functions for $C$ otherwise.